# Scala. NoSuchMethodException when instantiating trait

Tags: scala

After refactoring some projects, I I got the following Exception when calling a scala class that implements a trait from a Spring Boot application

> 8/06/22 13:32:26 ERROR SpringApplication: Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MLController' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/xxxx/environment/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/./xxxx/ikodaanalysis-mlserver-0.1.0.jar!/xxx/mlserver/MLController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [xxx.mlserver.MLController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ikoda.utilobjects.SparkConfProviderWithStreaming.$init$(Lxxx/utilobjects/SparkConfProviderWithStreaming;)V

I checked the dependencies and everything appeared to be present in the jar.
So why was I getting the Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40449675-nosuchmethoderror-thrown-with-scala-2-12). I felt it was probably a fairly common issue and worth reporting on SO.

> I assume it's down to Java 8 and Scala 2.12 expecting to find the "init" method in the ScalaDsl.class file (new style Traits as interfaces) rather than in ScalaDsl$class.class file (old style Traits as interface and supporting class).
>
> ......
>   I think the Scala 2.12 package needs to be compiled (not just run)
>   under Java 8 to avoid this problem.